# SetIconIndexでエラー

Tags: c++

現在、RAD Studio 10.3でプログラミングを行っています。

```cpp
void __fastcall TfrmMain::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
-----------------(中略)---------------
    pTray = new TTrayIcon(Application); 
-----------------(中略)---------------
    pTray->SetIconIndex(0);
-----------------(中略)---------------
}
```

SetIconIndex(0)の行で次のようなエラーが出てきました。

> [bcc32c エラー] Main.cpp(901): 'SetIconIndex' is a protected member of 'Vcl::Extctrls::TCustomTrayIcon'
>     vcl.ExtCtrls.hpp(2319): declared protected here

どうやら、アプリケーションの最小化をした時に、タスクトレーにアイコンを表示しておく機能なのですが、
このエラーの回避方法を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetIconIndexはIconIndexプロパティのセッターなので
pTray->IconIndex = 0;
で良いんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。助かります。